# Relatório não obedece formatação quando exportado para PDF

Tags: demoiselle, ireport, jasper-reports

Criei um relatório no iReport que contém formatação (fontes, negrito e itálico). No preview do próprio iReport aparece corretamente, mas quando uso dentro de um projeto demoiselle-jsf-jpa e exporto para PDF, não obedece a formatação.

Segui o wiki abaixo da comunidade Jaspersoft, que explica como usar o recurso de "font extensions" para resolver o problema:
http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/bold-and-underlined-fonts-not-rendering-pdf

Em resumo, pelo iReports é criado um JAR com as fontes e suas variações, o qual deve ser colocado no "ClassPath". Isso é o mesmo que colocar no build path? Eu tentei pelo Eclipse, adicionando o JAR no build path, mas não resolveu.

Alguém já passou por esse problema e conseguiu resolver?

demoiselle-jsf-jpa 2.4.2
JasperReports e iReport 4.0.1

Fernando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara, esses tempos passei por um problema parecido, o que acontecia era que o tamanho e fontes do relatório não configuravam no sistema, tenta procurar algum .jar com o tipo da fonte que você vai usar e colocar no modulo de relatório do seu projeto, atualiza sua lista de .jar's do ireport ou jasperreports. Foi isso que resolveu meu problema. Abraço! Duvida pergunta aê!

Comment: Obrigado, amigo, mas não funcionou. Até baixei o JAR de fontes "padrão" do Jasper (http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/archive/jasperreports/JasperReports%204.0.1/jasperreports-fonts-4.0.1.jar/download) e tentei usar a fonte "DejaVu Sans", que já vem pré configurada, mas aí é pior.. em vez de não aparecer a formatação, dá o erro net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException: Font 'DejaVu Sans' is not available to the JVM. Tentei colocar no classpath via parâmetro -classpath, na variável ambiente CLASSPATH, no buildpath junto com o arquivo do relatório, e nada.

Comment: Você colocou no módulo do relatório do seu projeto? Porque no Jasper ou Ireport vai funcionar filé, o problema é que seu projeto não entende o formato que você esta mandando! Tenta colocar o .jar nas biblioteca do seu projeto!

Comment: Era isso mesmo, amigo. Quando eu gerava o WAR para o servidor, o arquivo JAR das fontes não estava sendo incluído na pasta lib. Quando incluí manualmente funcionou. Obrigado.

Answer (score -3):

Galera estava com mesmo problema ao exportar para PDF
eu coloquei no meu POM as seguintes dependências:

net.sf.jasperreports
jasperreports
6.16.0


net.sf.jasperreports
jasperreports-fonts
6.16.0


net.sf.jasperreports
jasperreports-functions
6.16.0


net.sf.jasperreports
jasperreports-metadata
6.16.0


net.sf.jasperreports
jasperreports-chart-themes
6.16.0


net.sf.jasperreports
jasperreports-chart-customizers
6.16.0

e em alguns casos não respondeu algumas Tags utilizando a fonte Arial,
mais quando mudei para fonte DejaVuSans
deu tudo certo!!!
espero ajudar alguém ^^ !